# Is it fair to say that "macros don't compose"?

Tags: clojure, composition, macros

On [this blog post](http://aphyr.com/posts/305-clojure-from-the-ground-up-macros) aphyr (who is a brilliant programmer) states:

> Clojure macros come with some important restrictions. Because they’re expanded prior to evaluation, macros are invisible to functions. They can’t be composed functionally–you can’t `(map or ...)`, for instance.

The [classic example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531986/treat-clojure-macro-as-a-function#comment6307898_5532375) of this is:

```
(reduce and [true true false true])
;RuntimeException
```

Yet we can write:

```
(reduce #(and %1 %2) [true true false true])
;false
```

**Is 'macros don't compose' a valid claim?** Surely the only  valid point is that macros are not first class functions and shouldn't be treated as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this depends on what you mean by "compose". I would say that it's mostly true but can be taken too far.

First, note that in the quote you cited aphyr didn't say "macros don't compose"; the phrase was "can't be composed functionally". That more limited claim is indisputably true. Macros in Clojure aren't values[1]. They can't be passed as arguments to other functions or macros, can't be returned as the result of computations, and can't be stored in data structures.

There are, of course, ways to work around these limitations. Besides your `#(and %1 %2)` example, there's a sense in which the code below represents composition.

```
(ns some.macros
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [when when-not]))

(defmacro when [test & body]
  `(cond ~test (do ~@body)))

(defmacro when-not [test & body]
  `(when (not ~test) ~@body))
```

I intentionally used `cond` rather than `if` in the definition of `when` because `cond` is itself a macro.

But, back to the larger point, `#(and %1 %2)` isn't really an argument that macros compose, it's an argument that you can use macros within functions. And, because we have many powerful ways of working with functions, this is generally the best way to go. Use macros (when functions aren't appropriate) to abstract away boilerplate, repetitive code, but, when possible, ultimately expose as much of your API as possible as functions so that they can be stored in hash-maps, mapped over sequences of widgets, negated with `complement`, juxtaposed with `juxt`, and so on.

<sub>[1] It would be difficult for it to be otherwise. Imagine if macros were values and could be passed as arguments to functions. How could you compile code that used such a macro, given that its expansion wouldn't be known until runtime (and could vary between invokations of the function)?</sub>

**Addendum**

As a point of interest, consider that macros *are* functions, they're just treated specially by the compiler.

Check this out:

```
some.macros> (defn when [&form &env test & body]
               `(cond ~test (do ~@body)))
#<Var@1a37b98:
  #<macros$eval7806$when__7807 some.macros$eval7806$when__7807@d1cf9c>>
some.macros> (when nil nil true 1 2)
(clojure.core/cond true (do 1 2))
some.macros> (. #'when (setMacro))
nil
some.macros> (when true 1 2)
2
```

This is, in fact, exactly how `defmacro` works. (See [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-and.html) for an explanation of the `&form` and `&env` pseudo-arguments).

Comment: Thanks for this - this is awesome. Re "isn't really an argument that macros compose" - surely you can always wrap a macro in a function?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm sure there's a counterexample out there somewhere, but generally you can wrap a macro in a function when needed, although it may end up awkward or verbose. I think there are two possible responses though. One is the sort of technicality that it's still really the function that's composing. The other is that, if either a function or macro could do the job, you may as well use the function since it can be used in any way without needing to be wrapped, and macro-ness probably isn't providing any advantages.

Comment: As an example, `clojure.core/not-any?` is defined as `(comp not some)`. It's just not possible to define a macro as a composition of other macros in that way. I think the `cond`/`when`/`when-not` example is probably about as close as you can get but it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: "How could you compile code that used such a macro, given that its expansion wouldn't be known until runtime (and could vary between invokations of the function)?" Common Lisp macros do something akin to that, though

Comment: @user1737909, my explanation was perhaps not great but there's a distinction between macro-expansion time and runtime in Common Lisp as well. Macros are "gone" at runtime. See the "Macro Expansion Time vs. Runtime" section in [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html)